# Recurring task list sharepoint online

Tags: tasks, task-list

I'm attempting to create a recurring task list in sharepoint but I am having trouble on how to approach it. What I envisioned is a task list with tasks that need to be completed during various times of the month (1st, 15th, EOM, etc.). Is a task list the best way to approach this or another app more suitable?